# How to display groups name and members of groups?

Tags: python, ldap

Recently I work with freeIpa and Python and I stuck on one problem, how to to show name of group and then every members of these group?

I need to displey something like that:
Group1:
Member1,member2...
Group2:
Member3,member4..
....

I try something thats but  show every information from ldap

```
import ldap
from pprint import pprint

LdapServer= "MyServerAdress"
con=ldap.initialize(LdapServer)
con.simple_bind_s("UserDN","Password")
baseDN="cn=groups,cn=accounts,dc=MyLocalServer,dc=com"
groups=con.search(baseDN,ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE)
pprints(groups)
```

Comment: How are the groups stored? What have you tried?

Comment: I installed FreeIpa on the Centos from repo, then create a groups and users and now I need to export groups and users to flat file